# $\sin(3x)/2x$ to power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> Write to power series of $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(3x)}{2x}, \quad x\neq 0.$$

I try to get a series for $\sin(3x)$ with $x=0$ and multiplying the series with $2x$.

Is that right?

Comment: Maybe you devide instead of multiplying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Taylor series for the sine:
$$\sin{3x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{(3x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

We can write the function $f(x)$ as:

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin{3x}}{2x}=\frac{1}{2x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{(3x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{3^{2n+1}x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 3):

Just write taylor series for sin(3x) and the divide by 2x
$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{3^{2n+1}x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's completely fine. The Maclaurin series for $\sin$ is
$$\sin(t)=t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^5}{5!}+...$$
So letting $t=3x$,
$$\frac{1}{2x}\sin(3x)=\frac{1}{2x}\left(3x-\frac{(3x)^3}{3!}+\frac{(3x)^5}{5!}+...\right)$$
You can move the $(2x)^{-1}$ inside:
$$\frac{\sin(3x)}{2x}=\frac{3^1x^1}{2x}-\frac{3^3x^3}{2x\cdot3!}+\frac{3^5x^5}{2x\cdot5!}+...$$
Hopefully you can construct the general term from here?